# Какой вариант верный?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно должно звучать по-русски следующее предложение:  "Переоборудованные автобусы хотят вовсе запретить В использовании" или "Переоборудованные автобусы хотят вовсе запретить К использованию"& Или возможны оба варианта?

Answer (score 1):

Оба - плохо. Первый (в использовании) неверен грамматически, второй (к использованию) плох стилистически, канцелярит. Правильным вариантном считаю: *"Использовние переоборудованных автобусов хотят вовсе запретить"*.